How to find a specific distance upstream from a point
I am trying to find a simple way to map sections of a river which are covered by a Mink trap.
So I have a river layer and a points layer for where the traps are placed.
I want to select all rivers (including any tributaries) 500m upstream from where a trap is placed (a point) so I can visualise the areas covered.
It sounds vaguely simple but I'm struggling to find an answer. Can anyone link me in the right direction? Answers can be QGIS or ArcGIS.

RivEX for ArcPro has a tool that will generate the required nearby network.

Thanks @Hornbydd. I don't suppose there are any free methods as this requires a license? Working for a Charity, cost is an hurdle.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We are a problem-solving site. Open-ended opinion-based Questions are off-topic here. If your research  locates a solution with one GIS platform, and you try it, and it doesn't work as expected, then you'll have a problem which can be documented and asked about.

You can use Service Area From Layer:

Returns all the edges or parts of edges of a network that can be
reached within a distance or a time, starting from a point layer

I've set 1500 as distance, and Default direction = Backward direction to measure against the line direction:

